Can you pull information from local HTML files with Apps Script automatically to GSheets to work around limitations of =ImportHTML?
I've been trying to create a tracker for my team, which involves pulling data from a jira-like website. Unfortunately, unlike jira, there isn't an easy add-on for pulling data directly to a google sheet. I've attempted to use =ImportHTML as a function, but have found that it does not work with sites with authentication requirements, even if you have the log in information.
So, my hypothetical work around is to download the page as an html file and try to read the information directly off of that. Either from browsing local files, or browsing the files in a google drive, what I would LIKE to do is just paste the file into it's associated drive folder, so that the GScript will automatically read it and post it into a sheet within GSheets.
function doGet(){
  return getHtmlFile()
}

function onOpen(){
 const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

 ui.createMenu("EODR")
 .addItem("Modal dialog", "showModal")
 .addItem("Sidebar", "showSidebar")
 .addToUi()
}

function showModal(){
  const html = getHtmlFile()

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
   .showModalDialog(html, "Test")
}

function showSidebar(){
  const html = getHtmlFile()

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
   .showSidebar(html)
}

function getHtmlFile(){
  const htmlFileId = "//insert html field here"

  const blob = DriveApp 
   .getFileById(htmlFileId)
   .getBlob()
   .getDataAsString
 console.log(blob)
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(blob)
  .addMetaTag("viewport", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
  .setWidth(500)
  .setHeight(500)
  .setTitle("Test")

}

I have no experience in coding unfortunately, and the code above is what I've been able to cobble together from a tutorial. It can read an html file from a drive, but doesn't automatically fill in the information on the sheet. It is also limited in that is draws from the specific code of a html drive file, but it would be much more ideal if it could draw the information from any file placed in a folder, as the specific file would change daily.
If I can elaborate more, please don't hesitate to ask. Thank you!

Instead of web scraping, you should use the Jira-like API to get the information you want to get into Google Sheets. If the service doesn't have an API, look for the service's options to export the data that you need.

Pulling HTML files stored locally using Google Apps Script is impossible.
The above is because Google Apps Script can't access the user's local environment; instead of saving the HTML files locally, as you mentioned in the question, you might store them in Google Drive and read them from there.
However, this might not be enough to overcome the limitations of IMPORTHTML, the Google Sheets built-in function, and simple web scraping methods due to quotas and other restrictions and limitations. You may have to rely on complex processes, which is too convoluted compared with other options that are likely available to clients of cloud-based services.
One of the things that you might look into regarding the webpages having the data that you want to import is if they included the data as a "JSON" directly or pulled it from a static file, if that is the case, it might be helpful to know that a few years ago, someone created a Google Apps Script library, including code for a custom function named IMPORTJSON.
Related

Data Scraping With ImportHTML in Apps Script & Google Sheets
IMPORTHTML() doesn't work in this webpage structure
Creating a UrlFetchApp script to replace the Google Sheet importHTML function


Unfortunately it doesn't have an accessible API, and while there is a singular option to export as a CSV file, I do not have permission to do so. It's quite the unfortunate situation that the client responsible for the data based opted to create their own instead of using the functionally identical Jira, but alas, I have to work with what I'm given. If reading from drive would be too complicated, would you have any other suggestions for circumventing ImportHTML? As mentioned I have no experience in code, so there's likely many things I haven't thought of.

@DavidOliphant suggests you post a more specific question, including a [mcve] (code plus sample input file and the corresponding expected result). If you aren't able to create a "mcve" you might have to take some steps back, i.e., start by learning about the Document Object Model  (DOM) and methods to analyze and scrap data from webpages. P.D. This site already has many questions about web scraping using Class UrlFetchApp from Google Apps Script. Some use a library named Cheerio, but most heavily depend on the data to be extracted.
